# What the best way to persist data in Java application without SQL or any Database Sever?

Tags: java, netbeans, persistence, javadb

I wants create a desktop app that need to store data. This app can be used in various pc's. So, I don't want install sql server and more applications to make this. I want just create a file with all data that is stored, making backup easier and have a fast installation.
I thought use a JSON or XML file, or Excel (.xmls), but this appears hard to execute a searchs, or other operation.
So, before implements this I want a opinion.

Comment: Single user database - like H2?

Comment: how about an in-memory java db

Comment: Thank you guys. The Java DB appears the easiler option, do you can explain more about your use? I read the doc: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javadb-141163.html. But it's not clear if it meets my need.

Comment: "An embedded database should not be confused with an in-memory database such as SQLite. In an in-memory database, the data is stored entirely in the main memory for faster response with no permanent storage." So, Java DB not persist data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [com.typesafe.config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) or SQLite. It depend on data, that you must store. 
Another solution is to serialize your data class to XML\JSON with GSON or [xstream](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream)

Gson example:

```
public static class Entity {
    volatile int id;
    String name;
    transient long random;

    public Entity(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
//Create new entity
Entity entity = new Entity(100, "name");
entity.random = 1234;

//Serialize to JSON. Then you can save string to file
String json = gson.toJson(entity); // {"id":100,"name":"name"}
// On application start you can deserialize your entity from file
Entity read = gson.fromJson(json, Entity.class);
```

Comment: The SQLite solve my problem. But, I can’t insert and update data on database. Have more solutions? Or let me see a example of json serialization.

Comment: Why you cant insert and update data on database? You can store SQLite db file in your app dir like any other file like json or xml.

Comment: I read the docs of Oracle and other blogs, and I did understand that the SQLite only can make operations of read. Other operations like insert and update not works. But, all in all, inside netbeans all works, but when I make the jar file, the SQLite stop working. I did create a maven project too, but it did not solve.